# ASP.NET: Checkboxlist or checkbox

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm doing userlevel control in my website but i don't have any idea how to do this.

Here's the sample gui:

[image]

The main menu here is the Registrations and Reports. Then the submenu of Registrations are SubMenu1 and Submenu2. Then the submenu of Submenu1 and Submenu2 are Add and Edit. So my questions, how can I do it in asp.net? Tips and suggestions are okay also.

Scene:
So when I check the Registrations the submenu1/submenu2 and the ADD and EDit will be checked also...But if i unchecked the ADD of Submenu1 it will unchecked...

Comment: You need to catch the click events using jQuery/Javascript. Is that what you are looking for examples of? Are you using MVC or web forms?

Comment: @PeterSmith. I'm using WebForms

Answer (score 0):

You can controls to do that. Checkout Microsoft's treeview control: http://quickstarts.asp.net/quickstartv20/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/navigation/treeview.aspx

Or have a look at third party controls like:

- http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/treeview.aspx
- http://www.astreeview.com/astreeviewdemo/astreeviewdemo1.aspx

or many others.